# Using fscanf to receive an array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, character-arrays

I'm trying to take the input of floating numbers from a file and arrange it into an array.

The only trouble is that I don't know exactly how many floating numbers there will be each time though I do know that the max amount of floating numbers is 1000.

What I need to do is have fscanf take all the floating numbers but then stop at the next line, which is full of integers.

Here is what I have so far for this section:

```
for (repetition = 0; repetition <= 1000; repetition++)
{ 

    fscanf(userFile, "%f", &itemPrice[itemNumber]);
    itemNumber++;

}
```

But unfortunately, this continues on to assign array values to all of the other values in the next several lines.

I found another user input, `auctionItems` and used that to control the array length using `while(itemNumber < auctionItems)`

Comment: In `for` loop condition, you have done `itemPrice <= 1000` rather than `repetition <= 1000`.

Comment: Do you know that all the floating-point numbers will be on the same line, and that nothing else will be on that line?

Comment: `itemPrice <= 1000` --> `itemNumber < 1000`

Comment: I was messing around with the code, and I changed it to `item price <= 1000` but never changed it back. My original code is indeed `repitition <= 1000`  And yes, on this specific line it will only be floating numbers where as the previous and next line are integers.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `fscanf` is the number of items successfully read.  Use that to decide when to stop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
  int i;
  float ff[1000];
  char next_text[17];

  for (i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int n_read;

    n_read = fscanf(stdin, " %f", &( ff[i] ));
    if (n_read < 1) {
      fscanf(stdin, "%16s", next_text);
      next_text[16] = (char) 0;
      printf("Next text: '%s'\n", next_text);
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("Read %d items, %f .. %f\n",i,ff[0],ff[i-1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this method using fgetc and fputc:

```
for (repetition = 0; itemPrice <= 1000; repetition++)
{
    int c = fgetc(userFile);
    if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) break;
    fputc(c);


    fscanf(userFile, "%f", &itemPrice[itemNumber]);
    itemNumber++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is fairly close.  Just stop when scanning fails.

`fscanf()` returns the number of fields scanned or `EOF`.  In this case, checking for `1` is sufficient.

```
// for (repetition = 0; itemPrice <= 1000; repetition++)  Use <, not <= @Arpit
for (i = 0; i < 1000; )
{ 
    int retval = fscanf(userFile, "%f", &itemPrice[i]);
    if (retval != 1) break;
    i++;
}
```

A robust solution would detect unexpected data.  This solution simple goes until the end-of-file or non-float text is encountered.

---

[Edit] 
It appears OP has only 1 line of `float`s.  In that case code could read the whole line and then parse the buffer.

```
#define CHAR_PER_FLOAT_MAX  20
char buf[1000*(CHAR_PER_FLOAT_MAX + 1)];  // Some large buffer
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, input)== NULL) return;  // EOF or IO error

char *p = buf;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; ) { 
    int n = 0;
    if (sscanf(p, "%f %n", &itemPrice[i], &n) != 1) break;
    p += n;
    i++;
}   
if (*p) Handle_ExtraTextOnLine();

foo(itemPrice, i); // Use data
```

Another approach is to read direct from the file 1 `float` at a time and then look at the following white-space for an end-of-line.  Less elegant.

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; ) { 
    if (fscanf(input, "%f", &itemPrice[i]) != 1) {
      // need to add code to consume the rest of the line if processing is to continue.
      break;
      }
    i++;

    // look for standard white-space
    char buf[2];
    while (fscanf(input, "%1[ \f\n\r\t\v]", buf) == 1) {
      if (buf[0] == '\n') break;
    }
}   
foo(itemPrice, i); // Use data
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is still saving the integers from the next line as part of the floating number array `itemPrice[1000]`

Comment: @ Dakrid  Suggest posting a short example of the file input.  BTW: be sure to use `<` and not `<=` in `for (repetition = 0; repetition < 1000; repetition++)`

Comment: Is this because the array starts at 0? Therefore 0-999 would == 1000 values?

Comment: @Dakrid Yes, arrays are indexed starting at 0.  `for (repetition = 0; itemPrice <= 1000; repetition++)` would be 1001 iterations regardless of where indexing starts - certainly 1 too many.

Comment: So I plugged this in and adapted it to fit my programs declarations, only I am getting "underfined reference to `foo'"

Comment: @Dakrid [foo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) is a placeholder name for the function of your choice.  Simply replace with code that would use `itemPrice, itemNumber`.

Comment: So, on this line in the input file, there are six floating numbers, each separated by a space. The next line is integers, the first currently being 100. What I have in the code is, `printf("%f", itemPrice[6]);` and this is continually coming up as 100.00000. This is testing that the function is stopping at the floating numbers or continuing on to the next line. So far, it only does the latter, or produces the entire array as 0.

Comment: If you have read 6 `float`s into `itemPrice[0], itemPrice[1], itemPrice[2], ... itemPrice[5]`.  The value in `itemPrice[6]` is not initialized by this code.  BTW: see update in code: need to use consistent `repetition` or `itemPrice`.

Comment: Updated. And like I said, the amount of floating numbers each time is going to change based on the users input. I plugged in the last code you put in. It seems to be saving every other array? That was because you had two separate i++. I changed that but it is still going into the integers

Comment: @Dakrid Extra `i++` removed.  See that you removed the same one. Which method of the later 2 are you using?

Comment: I am using the less elegant of the two. I looked through the program and I may be able to define how many numbers are in the itemPrice. The second line of input declares how many items there will be and I am going to try to use that to define the array for itemPrice, while keeping the max at 1000. I will update when I get this done, may be a few hours, class in 30.

Answer (score 0):

```
char input[MAX];
while(fgets(input, MAX, userFile) != NULL){
    sscanf(input, "%lf", &itemPrice[itemNumber++]);
}
```